# How to downgrade CuDNN in Fedora?

Tags: fedora, python, gpu

I am installing tensorflow. After installation, I got compatibility issue. tensorflow library I have installed is not compatible with the CuDNN I think. How to solve this issue.

I am using Fedora 25.

```
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:925] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:951] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1080
major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.7335
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 7.92GiB
Free memory: 7.81GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:972] DMA: 0 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:982] 0:   Y 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1041] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
```

Error:

```
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:368] Loaded runtime CuDNN library: 6020 (compatibility version 6000) but source was compiled with 5105 (compatibility version 5100).  If using a binary install, upgrade your CuDNN library to match.  If building from sources, make sure the library loaded at runtime matches a compatible version specified during compile configuration.
F tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_ops.cc:526] Check failed: stream->parent()->GetConvolveAlgorithms(&algorithms)
```

Comment: Where did you install it from?

Comment: https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn here is the link.

Comment: So download the older version from there, if they provide it. If they do not provide it, you are probably out of luck.